# How to fix the default language in the url redirection

Tags: angular8

After upgrade from angular 7 to angular 8, my url is not redirected to `/en`, the `en` is my default language.

I use `ng serve --configuration:en` to generate the build for the English version, so I want when we have http://www.my-app.com --> redirect to http://www.my-app.com/en by default

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "m1",
        loadChildren: () => import("./m1/m1.module").then(m => m.M1Module)
    },
    {
        path: "m2",
        loadChildren: () => import("./m2/m2.module").then(m => m.M2Module),
    },    {   path: "",
        redirectTo: "m1/home",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppBrowserRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Can you post your router configs

Comment: import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "m1",
        loadChildren: () => import("./m1/m1.module").then(m => m.M1Module)
    },
    {
        path: "m2",
        loadChildren: () => import("./m2/m2.module").then(m => m.M2Module),
    },    {   path: "",
        redirectTo: "m1/home",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppBrowserRoutingModule { }